# Using <button> instead of <input> with .Net

Tags: webforms

I am trying to style a web page which is created by .net. So I am having issues on some buttons and other elements. My main issue is the bottons because in design template some circle buttons etc are used but .Net keeps giving `<input>` elements :(

Using `<asp:Button>` creates `<input>` element but what should I use to get a `<button>` element? Because I cannot apply the styles to an `<input>` element.

I have asked the code for the page, I did not code this so I do not know if it is MVC or not. All I need is to get a ... in the rendered HTML. What can I say to my coder friend so that he makes this work?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Portall.Admin.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="dvMainContainer">
            <div class="header" >
                <span>Login</span>
            </div>
            <div class="dvLoginInfo">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="cmdLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="cmdLogin_Click" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Portall.Admin
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        AdminBL.AdminBusinessLayer adminBsLayer = new AdminBL.AdminBusinessLayer();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblInfo.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AdminUser currentUser = null;

            try
            {
                currentUser = adminBsLayer.Login(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                lblInfo.Text = "A database problem occured.";
                return;
            }

            if (currentUser.UserId <= 0)
            {
                lblInfo.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                return;
            }

            Session["AdminUser"] = currentUser;
            Response.Redirect("UserEntry.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest trying to improve/clarify your question. I think it's improbable that the current form will get you a helpful answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to happen vs what is currently happening?

Comment: I have added the code. Sorry did not realize my question was so vauge:( Thank you for you help.

Comment: Did you try to... **replace** `<asp:Button>` **with plain HTML** `<button>`? You'll bypass default ASP.NET renderer for buttons but everything else will still work (just remember to update events, for example `OnClick` is `onserverclick`).

Comment: @Adriano thank you! But I am not so sure, he says it may be problem with events, which did not make sense to me:( You say remember to update events, I asked for code behind. How should I change it? Cause I asked to ass onserverclick but it is not enough I guess:(

Comment: It should be, what he will not get is data binding and the same behavior for postback but here it shouldn't be an issue... `<button id="cmdLogin" runat="server"     onserverclick="cmdLogin_Click">Login</button>`. ASP.NET should wrap that for you in a server object (I'm not sure if it'll use `asp:Button` or a simple `asp:Literal`...)

Comment: @Adriano sorry :( just did not work. Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'cmdLogin', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton). Thats why I do not like .net :) actally I dont code but somehow there is always a problem with it...

Comment: After change...did you **rebuild** the web site?

Comment: @Adriano he told he did compile it. Then I hit another thing in .Net called asp:ImageButton :) I asked him to change it to image button and voila! I could use styling properly on the button now:D Thank you for your directions

Answer (score 3):

Download CSSFriendyControlAdapters and use it to create a button server control. You can find it here:

http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/

Just take a look at the simplest control and it should be easy enough to modify it to emit a button. You don't have to change your existing controls, it will use you adapter instead.

If you don't care about having too much control and rendering options, you can simply use the built-in HTMLButton control:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <button ID="cmdLogin" runat="server" OnServerClick="cmdLogin_Click">
         Login
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `<asp:ImageButton />` lets me to add any styling I need, i.e. background image, gradients etc.
For more information on using reffer to [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx)